# How to have image data stored defaultly inside Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have an image attached as a logo for my GUI, currently, before OpeningFcn I am using imread to get the logo.

But I want to move my code between different computers and not planning to have the logo image along with the guide. Is it possible to define a function that creates the image I want?

Like,

```
imgData = createImg(); % function call

function imgData = createImg()
% imgData = imread('peppers.png'); % usual way
imgData = % idk do something to have it in this function definition.
end
```

**Update:** I followed what you said

```
imgData = imread('logo_Img.png');
csvwrite('imgDataLogical.txt',logical(imgData(:,:,1)));

function logical_idx = my_createImg()
% imgData = imread('peppers.png'); % usual way
logical_idx = [... % data...]; % data from txt file
end


logical_img = my_createImg();
[red_img,green_img,blue_img] = deal(uint8(255*(logical_img == 1)));
red_img(logical_img == 1) = 220; red_img(logical_img ~= 1) = 230;
green_img(logical_img == 1) = 20; green_img(logical_img ~= 1) = 230;
blue_img(logical_img == 1) = 60; blue_img(logical_img ~= 1) = 230;
fullImg = cat(3,red_img,green_img,blue_img);
figure, imshow(fullImg)
```

I think this is written pretty bad.

Any ideas to make it good.

Thanks,

Gopi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to copy-paste the data into the M-file.

Your M-file would look like this:

```
function imgData = createImg()
% imgData = imread('peppers.png'); % usual way
imgDataR = [...
   43, 86, 43, 54, 123, 43, 132, ... (etc.)
];
imgDataG = [...
   ... (more data here)
];
imgDataB = [...
   ... (more data here)
];
imgData = cat(3, imgDataR, imgDataG, imgDataB);
end
```

To generate that data, read in the image and write it to text file using [`csvwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html):

```
imgData = imread('peppers.png');
csvwrite('imgDataR.txt',imgData(:,:,1));
csvwrite('imgDataG.txt',imgData(:,:,2));
csvwrite('imgDataB.txt',imgData(:,:,3));
```

And then open those text files and copy-paste the data to your M-file.

---

Though if you have a logo, you probably have few colors. It might be better to store it as an index matrix and a color map. But the principle would be the same.

To use a color map do as follows:

```
function logical_idx = my_createImg()
% imgData = imread('peppers.png'); % usual way
index = [... % data...]; % should have values 1 and 2
colmap = uint8([220,20,60; 230,230,230]);
imgData = colmap(index,:);
imgData = reshape(imgData,[size(index),3]);
end
```

Your `index` matrix should have values 1 and 2 (or higher numbers if you have more colors). To go from the logical matrix you have now to this, simply add 1. You use this matrix to index into the color map. You then need to reshape the output to have the correct sizes.

Comment: It works. But the memory usage of my RAM spikes to like 4GB doing this. My image is of size 718*4100*3

Comment: @Gopi: Yes, that's a large image for a logo. But I don't expect that to take up 4 GB, but rather 8 MB. Even written out in text format, since you only have 1 and 0 values, it shouldn't take up more than two or three times that. But they way you do indexing is kind of expensive. I have edited the answer to show how to index into a color map.